# How to open multiple instances of Android Studio or instances of Same Project but different branch simultaneously on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, git, bitbucket

I have been struggling to manage two branches of a Project at the same time. By Manage, I mean, to be able to open the Project(same) twice or more than than.

Suppose, on Windows, I create a new Desktop and open Android Studio in this. I can open Google Chrome and other apps but opening the entire Android Studio simultaneously is not possible.

I don't find any such questions on SO. isn't there a need for that?

I just want to open and edit and code on two branches of the same Project on Windows and it need not to be on a different desktop.

Comment: You could clone the Project again into another folder location on your computer (maybe named "project-branched"), then you can use that folder location for the other branch you want to view/edit at the same time.

Comment: Okay. That is what I was doing. I was just wondering if we could open a new Desktop and open Android Studio just like Chrome. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 6):

You cant work with same project, but with different branches simultaneously - just because `branch` - is a changes in sources and when you switching branch, you make changes nf files in project folder.
So solution - use different folders or better uses difftools build-in in android studio to compare sources of branches.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I find a need to open both branches simultaneously. What I do is I clone the project into another folder and switch it on the desired branch. When Android Studio is currently open with a project, opening another project will prompt: Where would you like to open? Choose "New Window" as opposed to "This Window". Now you have your 2 branches open at the same time.

Don't forget to update/rebase the 2nd folder as necessary.